# Wordpress posts with Spotify <iframe> in excerpt/description

Tags: wordpress, spotify

I need to display the spotify preview along with the post thumbnail on the archive page.

It doesn't necessarily have to embedded on the Excerpt, but I'm wondering how is it possible to create a iframe per post which is easy to mantain (using a simple posting system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things I can think about - 1st you can actually create your iFrame inside the archive.php  and the excerpt field to be just the url, so inside the file you can have something like:

```
//the loop
...//some content
<iframe src="<?=get_the_excerpt()?>"></iframe>
...//more content
//end loop
```

2nd thing I can think about is too use some pluging to add extra fields to your posts which you can call. I personally like [CMB2](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2) they have a really good [documentation](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types) and all sorts of custom fields you can add to your posts.